# Detect when image not found using Compose Coil

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, coil

I am populating my images using coil in jetpack compose and the issue I face is that I am not able to programmatically identify if the url is no longer valid.

```
val imageUrl = "www.someinvalidurl.com"
val painter = rememberImagePainter(
    data = imageUrl
)

Image(
    painter = painter
)
```

The url was previously valid but is not valid anymore. Coil shows the default placeholder url but then I want to identify this failure and attempt to get an image from a different url. I have tried this,

```
if (painter.state is ImagePainter.State.Error) {
    //failed so try to get an image from a different url
}
```

But the problem with this is that this block is called even for valid urls.

I am using the following version of coil :

```
implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:1.4.0")
```

Is there a different right way of identifying invalid URLs in coil while using jetpack compose

Comment: This is the correct way of detecting error, in my case it's not called for valid URLs. If it's `ImagePainter.State.Error` the image is not gonna be shown. But the error may be not only because of invalid URL, for example you may have weak connection.  Please provide a URL which fails to you and include the error description provided by the state, you can add a log to see it.

Comment: I thought so too but I am not sure if it's a bug but for my code, this doesn't work. The accepted below answer solves my problem thou...

Comment: At least check out the error description. Proposed solution is not really clean

Comment: @PhilipDukhov I cleaned up the code by referencing the response code instead of the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a listener that checks for exceptions. In this sample, the file extension should be "jpg" but I removed the "g" to test that the image does not exist:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        startActivity(intent)

        setContent {
            val imageUrl = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3a/Cat03.jpg/1200px-Cat03.jp"
            val painter = rememberImagePainter(
                data = imageUrl,
                builder = {
                    this.listener(
                        onError = {request, ex ->
                            if ((ex as HttpException).response.code() == 400) {
                                // Image not found
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            )

            Image(
                painter = painter,
                contentDescription = null
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried above same  image not loading background is empty.
But, this works Image(painterResource(R.drawable.actual2),"content description")